# Alternative to phonegap super.loadurl(); function

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Currently my app is working fine and I have used jquery mobile and phonegap and is only targeted at android users. The only phonegap code i am using is:

super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

By using jquery mobile and phonegap my application size has increased dramatically. Is there an alternative way to achieve the functionality of super.loadUrl() function just using plain java or java.net package.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your application size is not increased by this function. this is due to use of jquery mobile. when we use jquery mobile, it loads entire jquery mobile functions and files to one html. thats why it make app heavy and slower. So the suggestion would be to use plain javascript and jquery. i have also experienced this kind of problem. :)